# How to get data from a method using this keyword

Tags: c#

There is a method in the Messages class called `questionWhatisYourName()` this method is called by another method called `questionSurname()` this method is called by the Main Method of the Class Program.
Is it possible to return the data from the `questionWhatisYourName()` into the `questionSurname()` with out calling it in the messages Class? Maybe I should pass it as an argument to the `questionSurname()` method?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class TextEffects
{
    public void drawLine() {
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
    }
    public void drawLine(String linetype)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(linetype +
        linetype + linetype + linetype + linetype + linetype + linetype + linetype + linetype + linetype
        + linetype + linetype + linetype + linetype + linetype + linetype + linetype + linetype);
    }

}
class Messages
{
    public void hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello and welcome.");
    }
    public String questionWhatIsYourName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        String name = Console.ReadLine();
        return name;
    }
    public void questionSurname()
    {
        String myname = this.questionWhatIsYourName();
        Console.WriteLine(myname + " what is your surname?");

    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TextEffects texteffects = new TextEffects();
        Messages messages = new Messages();
        texteffects.drawLine("+");
        messages.hello();
        messages.questionSurname();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, pass it in as a string argument.

```
public void questionSurname(string myname)
{
    // ...
}
```

Call it like this:

```
string name = messages.questionWhatIsYourName();
messages.questionSurname(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the Name to the class Propeties and use it like that:

```
 class Messages
 {
     private string myName;
     public void Hello()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Hello and welcome.");
     }
     public void QuestionWhatIsYourName()
     {
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        myName = Console.ReadLine();            
     }
     public void QuestionSurname()
     {
         QuestionWhatIsYourName();
         Console.WriteLine(myname + " what is your surname?");
     } 
}
```

Note that your code is not statndard. methods should be begin with uppper case
and the name of the class messages just doesn't describe what that class responsible of.